# Inheritance with JPA without @Inheritance

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

is there a design model to inherit an entity with jpa and define a @OneToOne relationship with this same entity without using @Inheritance.

Example : An entity A that inherits from B and contains a @OneToOne relationship with entity B

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in the database? What you describe may work, but relations to ‘B’ must only be ‘B’ instances- it isn’t clear why you wouldn’t use the inheritance annotation

Comment: After thinking about it, there would be 2 primary keys. One for entity A and another for B. It doesn't seem relevant in reality. Sorry.